How EXACTLY is Masterwork Crafting Done in DA:I?
When I search YouTube; the best source I have found to date on DA:I Masterworks Crafting is this, 

 yet they make absolutely no mention of Dragon Teeth, Bear Claws, or any other Masterworks percentage chance item. What I'm trying to find out is the answer to a few very simple questions related to Masterwork Crafting. These Crafting Materials are definitely indicating there is a percentage chance that any Masterwork Item Crafting attempt can fail to produce the desired item:

If a Fade-Touched Material goes into the Masterwork slot on any Masterworks Schematic; then where do these Masterworks Percentage Chance of Success Materials go?
How/Where are these Masterworks Crafting Percentage chance of Success Components used?
If these Masterworks Percentage Chance Components FULLY IMPLY only a Masterworks percentage chance of success; then what happens to all of the crafting materials placed into each of the Schematic Slots when the Masterworks Item Crafting attempt results in a failure?

